# Convert text data to user format in Python

Tags: python

I have a data set which I will read from the text file:

```
0.0000000e+000 -1.4275799e-003  
2.0000000e-002 -1.1012760e-002  
4.0000000e-002 -1.0298970e-002  
6.0000000e-002 -8.9733599e-003  
8.0000000e-002 -9.6871497e-003  
1.0000000e-001 -1.2236400e-002  
1.2000000e-001 -1.4479739e-002  
1.4000000e-001 -1.3052160e-002  
1.6000000e-001 -1.1216700e-002  
1.8000000e-001 -8.6674497e-003  
2.0000000e-001 -8.6674497e-003  
2.2000000e-001 -1.3358070e-002  
2.4000000e-001 -1.7946720e-002  
2.6000000e-001 -1.9782179e-002
```

I want to convert after reading the text file into a format as:

```
(0.0000000e+000, -1.4275799e-003), (2.0000000e-002, -1.1012760e-002), (4.0000000e-002, -1.0298970e-002), ..., (2.6000000e-001, -1.9782179e-002)
```

which should be arranged in a single row.

Can anyone kindly help me regarding this? I have the code as follows:

```
with open('1.txt') as f:    
    for line in f:    
        n0 = map(float, line.split())    
        n1 = tuple(n0)    
        n2 = zip(n1)    
        print n0
```

I am not getting any error, however, the problem is the `zip` command is not giving me the desired format in row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should get the job done:

```py
def load_data(fn):
    with open(fn) as f:    
        lines = f.readlines()
    return [tuple([float(item) for item in line.split()]) for line in lines]

def display_data(lst):
    return lst.__repr__()[1:-1]

ppp = load_data('1.txt')

print(display_data(ppp))
#(0.0, -0.0014275799), (0.02, -0.01101276), (0.04, -0.01029897), (0.06, -0.0089733599), (0.08, -0.0096871497), (0.1, -0.0122364), (0.12, -0.014479739), (0.14, -0.01305216), (0.16, -0.0112167), (0.18, -0.0086674497), (0.2, -0.0086674497), (0.22, -0.01335807), (0.24, -0.01794672), (0.26, -0.019782179)

print(ppp)
#[(0.0, -0.0014275799),
# (0.02, -0.01101276),
# (0.04, -0.01029897),
# (0.06, -0.0089733599),
# (0.08, -0.0096871497),
# (0.1, -0.0122364),
# (0.12, -0.014479739),
# (0.14, -0.01305216),
# (0.16, -0.0112167),
# (0.18, -0.0086674497),
# (0.2, -0.0086674497),
# (0.22, -0.01335807),
# (0.24, -0.01794672),
# (0.26, -0.019782179)]
```

Comment: Yes I got the result earlier also. However, my question was to arrange the result in the format shown above in which I am stuck. Python is giving me this:
(0.0, -0.0014275799)  
(0.02, -0.01101276)  
(0.04, -0.01029897)
(0.06, -0.0089733599)
(0.08, -0.0096871497)
(0.1, -0.0122364)
(0.12, -0.014479739)
(0.14, -0.01305216)
(0.16, -0.0112167)
(0.18, -0.0086674497)
(0.2, -0.0086674497)
(0.22, -0.01335807)
(0.24, -0.01794672)
(0.26, -0.019782179)

The set of values are in columns and comma separator is missing after each set.

Comment: Thank you Tonechas, still I am getting the same results.
The output should be in a single row (0.0000000e+000, -1.4275799e-003), (2.0000000e-002, -1.1012760e-002), ... There should be a comma after each bracket ends, except the last one.

Comment: Thank you very much Tonechas. This code will help me in solving the rest of my problem.

Comment: Dear Tonechas, could you please help me in creating an output variable which gives the desired result, as I don't want to print it always?

Comment: What type should such a variable be? A string?

Comment: Not a string. The output is seen through print function, which should be stored in variable.
For ex: ppp should store (0, -0.00142758), (0.02, -0.0110128), (0.04, -0.010299), ..., (0.26, -0.019782179)

Comment: i am not understanding where and how to use these functions. Can you attach the script which contains the whole code?

Comment: The print display_data(ppp) displays the required result, however, the result is not stored anywhere, which I require. I think the issue is trivial if you can sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("1.txt" , "rb") as txtfile:
        outputstr = ""
        ioreader = txtfile.read()
        for line in ioreader.split("\n"):
            outputstr += str(tuple(line.split("\t")))
            outputstr += ","
        print outputstr
```

Comment: Thank you Kanagaraj dhanapal for the effort. However, the desired result is not achieved.

Comment: do you want single line of out put with comma separated ?

Comment: Yes, the output should be (0.0000000e+000, -1.4275799e-003), (2.0000000e-002, -1.1012760e-002), ...

There should be a comma after each bracket ends.

Comment: You are almost there. However, you need to remove the string before getting the desired output.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: dear friend, we can provide the answer for that question many ways. if you want most efficient one, let me know i will do it for you. thanks

Comment: Dear Dhanapal, yes sure you can present it. As robust codes are always helpful in saving time for many complex analyses.